# How do I clean up the classes properly in Lua and C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, lua

I have used Luabind to bind a class to Lua. I need to make sure the class is correctly disposed of when it is destructed or made null through `myClass = nil`.

This class adds itself to a static list inside itself like this:

```
template<typename T>
class component : public componentInterface
{
        public:
                static std::list<componentInterface *> list;
                component() : componentInterface()
                {
                        di::component<T>::list.push_back(this);
                }
                ~component()
                {
                        di::component<T>::list.remove(this);
                }
};
```

And when the destructor is called it promptly removes itself from the list.

Comment: What about copy constructor?

Comment: When you say `class` in your question, you mostly mean object or instance

Comment: @KarthikT Yea pretty much.

Comment: And what? (close to -1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. So long as Lua is creating the object, or Lua has adopted the object, Luabind will make sure that the destructor will be called.

However, Lua is garbage collected. This means that the destructor will not necessarily be called *immediately* after the last reference to the object is removed. Indeed, Lua can wait essentially indefinitely, until the actual lua_State object is released.

If more immediacy is important to you, then you can do one of the following:

- Have a `dispose` method on the object that Lua can call to destroy it early. It is therefore Lua's responsibility to *not* use the object after making this call.
- Execute the garbage collector by [calling `collectgarbage`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage), so that the garbage is collected.